# sending sms through java

Tags: java, sms

hi i am trying to send a sms through java i have downloaded mail.jar and set to classpath
below is my java code saved by SMTPSend.java and error plz guide me...

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SMTPSend {

    public SMTPSend() {
    }

    public void msgsend() {

        String username = "MySMSUsername";
        String password = "MyPassword";
        String smtphost = "MySMSHost.com";
        String compression = "My SMS Compression Information";
        String from = "mySMSUsername@MySMSHost.com";
        String to = "9762285104";
        String body = "Hello SMS World!";
        Transport myTransport = null;

        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();

            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};

            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);

            msg.setSubject(compression);

            msg.setText(body);

            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            myTransport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

            myTransport.connect(smtphost, username, password);

            msg.saveChanges();

            myTransport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

            myTransport.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

SMTPSend smtpSend = new SMTPSend();

smtpSend.msgsend();

}

}
```

and i get following error when i run the code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFounderror: SMTPSend
```

Comment: Now the formatting is even worse...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Now please indent your code the Java way.

Comment: Where's your main method?  That's where the issue is, not this class.

Comment: sorry for trouble im newbie ..

Comment: Not a problem, but you've got to post the code from the class with your main() method.

Answer (score 3):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", SMTP_PORT);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

You have not mentioned which port is used for sending message.
   You have to do something like this `SMTP_PORT = "465"`.